# Sharing .AspNet.ApplicationCookie between two MVC projects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, cookies

I have a Web project to login our users. It signs a user in, creates the ".AspNet.ApplicationCookie" cookie and then redirects to a page "~/Views/../Redirect.cshtml" that will choose, based on some rules, what will be the Website user will be redirected to. Very simple, a "redirecting..." message and a setTimeout function.

The problem is...website 2 does not recognize cookie created by site 1 and just moves the user back to site 1.

Some information:
1 - Works running both sites locally
2 - Site 1 and 2 are in the same server running on the same domain, just different ports.
3 - Both sites share the same ApplicationUserManager.Create call since I moved this class to a Domain project.

Startup.cs is as follows:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(AccountDbContext.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

            // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
            // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
            // Configure the sign in cookie
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                {
                    // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                    // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                        regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie))
                }
            });
            app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

            // Enables the application to temporarily store user information when they are verifying the second factor in the two-factor authentication process.
            app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

            // Enables the application to remember the second login verification factor such as phone or email.
            // Once you check this option, your second step of verification during the login process will be remembered on the device where you logged in from.
            // This is similar to the RememberMe option when you log in.
            app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was the Application Pool. All sites sharing the same cookie need to run on the same Application Pool. Once I set them all to use the same, it worked just fine.